# openpyxel memory issue (template excel-file)

Tags: python, excel, templates, openpyxl

I have a bit of a memory problem atm.

I've inherited an excel-template file which contains conditional formatting, formulas, some VBA-scripts and roughly 30 sheets. The template is basically empty initially and depending on the situtation I want to fill 1-10 of these sheets with values. The rest of the sheets will use the information that I update and fill out the rest.

The data is stored in a database and I use **python and openpyxl** to retrieve the data and write the excel. Conceptually it works like a charm.

However, I recently added some conditional formatting on 5 sheets and I now run into a memory problem. The process is killed.

The simplified process is this:

1. read template file
2. update data (this iterates through both sheets and cells so, a lot of looping going on)
3. store new file

Sample code:

```
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(TEMPLATE_FILE, keep_vba=True)
    ws = wb[SHEETNAMEn]
    ws.cell(row=rownum,column=colnum).value = theValue
    wb.save(newFilename)
```

So, I need some pointers on how to get this working/optimize it.

Comment: It's a piece of string question: without the file it's really difficult to say what's using the memory.

Comment: Exactly what's using up the memory I do not know. But it is related to adding conditional formatting. I'm more interested in what I can do to minimize memory usage in general, from a design perspective...
i.e what would be the best practice approach

Comment: To clarify, I do not see this as a bug or anything like that, I just have limited resources on the machine running this. One solution is to upgrade the hardware, but I'd like to upgrade the code to be less memory intensive if possible

Comment: At the moment there is really a lot that can be done if you're going to edit an existing file as all cells need to be converted into Python objects. 2.5 includes a new CellRange object but this is only really relevant for DataValidations not ConditionalFormatting. There are tools you can use to look at memory use but StackOverflow isn't really suitable for an extended discusssion.

Comment: OK, thanks for the input. I'll see if I can upgrade the ram to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: It's possible that Excel is caching the external data. This can be really memory intensive. You can try using `keep_links=False` when opening the file. This will drop any caching and should reduce memory use. But I've never tried this with a db connection.